# How to display product quantity in Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm using one of the default themes included with [prestashop-1.6](/questions/tagged/prestashop-1.6).  Is it possible to display product quantity values for a product based on size and color within the product box on the homepage?

Comment: Will you please add few screenshots and code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this thread on Prestashop.com forum](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/158702-add-in-stock-quantity-to-product-list-of-default-theme/).  It looks like someone else asked a similar question and was able to get it working with this code:

```
{*Added quantity in stock*}
<!-- availability -->
<p id="availability_statut"{if ($product.quantity <= 0 && !$product.available_later && $allow_oosp) OR ($product.quantity > 0 && !$product.available_now) OR !$product.available_for_order OR $PS_CATALOG_MODE} style="display: none;"{/if}>
    <span id="availability_label">{l s='Availability:'}</span>
    <span id="availability_value"{if $product.quantity <= 0} class="warning_inline"{/if}>
        {if $product.quantity <= 0}{if $allow_oosp}{$product.available_later}{else}{l s='This product is no longer in stock'}{/if}{else}{$product.available_now}{/if}
    </span>
</p>

<!-- number of item in stock -->
{*if ($display_qties == 1 && !$PS_CATALOG_MODE && $product.available_for_order) *}
<p id="pQuantityAvailable"{if $product.quantity <= 0} style="display: none;"{/if}>
    <span id="quantityAvailable">{$product.quantity|intval}</span>
    <span {if $product.quantity > 1} style="display: none;"{/if} id="quantityAvailableTxt">{l s='item in stock'}</span>
    <span {if $product.quantity == 1} style="display: none;"{/if} id="quantityAvailableTxtMultiple">{l s='items in stock'}</span>
</p>

<!-- Out of stock hook -->
<p id="oosHook"{if $product.quantity > 0} style="display: none;"{/if}>
    {$HOOK_PRODUCT_OOS}
</p>

<p class="warning_inline" id="last_quantities"{if ($product.quantity > $last_qties OR $product.quantity <= 0) OR $allow_oosp OR !$product.available_for_order OR $PS_CATALOG_MODE} style="display: none"{/if} >{l s='Warning: Last items in stock!'}</p>
{*End Added quantity in stock*}
```

---

and in [this other post also on Prestashop.com](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/253098-displaying-quantity-by-sizes/), someone reported that they were able to display quantities specific to the product size attribute using [this Prestashop module](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/40185-module-attribute-grid-show-attributes-as-a-grid-add-multiple-combinations-with-1-click/).
{*/if*}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The above code only provide the quantity of product. Do you have idea how to get quantity based on size and color? I checked it in post but could not find the suitable solution for it. That module you mentioned is for product display page and not for home page.

Comment: I do not sorry.  And am not currently working on Prestashop any longer.  I just was sharing what I had seen.  The guys over on the Prestashop forum are pretty helpful, if you have not already you may want to try asking over there.  Let me know if you find your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically product list already show some attributes - for example, colors. Product colors have a special method to append color selection to each product box in a list.

Therefore, we should follow this method if we do not wish to create a specific module.

Because we have to change some code, we must do and override (because we're not creating a module).

Method `addColorsToProductList` as a variable $product['color_list'] to each product that will be displayed in a list. We should and can add information about quantities and combinations here (it's probably the easiest way).

To get info about the combinations, I looked at `AdminProductsController.php @ Line 4263`. You should look at this method and also `addColorsToProductList`. Below is a pseudo-code (not fully complete, I can't write it all out for yo, but it shows the idea):

override/classes/controller/FrontController.php

```
FrontController extends FrontControllerCore {

    public function addColorsToProductList(&$products)
    {
        // You may need to modify the parent code if the caching ignores your changes

        // Disable this if you dont want to add colors seperately;
        parent::addColorsToProductList($products);


        // @see AdminProductsController.php @ Line 4263
        foreach($products as &$p)
        {
            $attributes = $p->getAttributesResume($this->context->language->id);

            foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
            {
                // You may check if product_attribute is color + size here

                $id_product_attribute = $attribute['id_product_attribute'];
                $qty = StockAvailable::getQuantityAvailableByProduct((int)$obj->id, id_product_attribute);

                $p['product_attributes'][$id_product_attribute]['qty'] = $qty;
                $p['product_attributes'][$id_product_attribute]['name'] =  $attribute['attribute_designation'];

                // If you need individual color + size and their data, you will probably have to do some SQL,
                // because getAttributesResume doesn SQL to get this data too.
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Aftert doing this you will be able to use `product_attributes` inside your templates:

product-list.tpl

```
{if isset($product.color_list)}
    <div class="color-list-container">{$product.color_list}</div>
{/if}

<p>
{foreach $product.product_attributes as $pa}
    {$pa.qty} - {$pa.name} <br>
{/foreach}
</p>
```

Cheers